# Arc Collector offline map - Copies of a map layer not downloading correctly

Tags: layers, offline, arcgis-collector

I have an Arc Collector project on the go and everything is working great except for one part of the offline mode. I encountered an issue with the offline version of the map displaying the layers correctly.

The map contains an unfiltered layer of a dataset and it also has additional layers of the same dataset but they have been filtered to display only certain portions of that data.

When working with the map in Collector in online mode everything works great. You can make changes to the unfiltered and filtered layers and the changes display correctly in both.

In offline mode, the layers are downloaded and show up correctly in the layer selection screen. The problem is that all of the versions of the layer, filtered and unfiltered, do not display on the map properly and display randomly as one of the versions of the layer.

For example I have layers A,B, and C. A,B and C all show up in the layer selection list but they all display as C on the map.

I'm trying to avoid having separate files for each set of data in the filtered layers if possible.

Is there any way of having multiple layers referencing the same dataset display properly in offline mode?

Are there filtering options within Collector that I missed?

Comment: They can't even give you a legend in collector; what makes you think ESRI would bother properly applying definition queries?

Comment: Are you using web map filters or query definitions? Web map filters are not supported in offline mode so you will see some issues with those when taken offline.